# the features of the action of $\Gamma = \langle \gamma \rangle$ on $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: manifolds, group-actions, hyperbolic-geometry, projective-space, complex-manifolds

Let $\gamma$ be an **Elliptic** element of ${\rm PSL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ representing an **Irrational** rotation.

Let $\Gamma$ be the subgroup of ${\rm PSL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ generated by $\gamma$ (i.e., $\Gamma = \langle \gamma \rangle$).

Let $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$ be the **Complex Projective Line**.

Suppose the group $\Gamma$ acting on $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$.

What are the main features (properties) of the action of the group $\Gamma$ on $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: Are you looking for anything in particular? You can conjugate $\gamma$ and $\Gamma$ so that $0$ and $\infty$ are fixed. After that conjugation, $\gamma$ is simply multiplication by $e^{2\pi r}$ for some irrational $r$, hence $\Gamma$ is an action of $\mathbb Z$ where each $n \in \mathbb Z$ acts on $\mathbb C \mathbb P^1 = \mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}$ multiplying by $e^{2 \pi rn}$. Each circle centered on the origin is preserved, and the restriction of the action to each such circle has dense orbits and is ergodic. Frankly, not much is going on here and I am running out of things to say.

Comment: @LeeMosher the element $\gamma$ can be written as follows $\gamma(z)=ze^{2 \pi i r}$?

Comment: Yes, that's right, after conjugation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll elaborate on my comment, to turn it into an answer.

First, the action of $\gamma$ on $\mathbb CP^1$ has two fixed points $P,Q \in \mathbb CP^1$, which one can easily seen by solving the equation $Mz=z$ where the matrix $M \in \text{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$ represents $\gamma \in \text{PSL}(2,\mathbb C)$.

Next, there exists an element $\delta \in \text{PSL}(2,\mathbb C)$ taking those two points $P$ and $Q$ to $0$ and $\infty$. When you conjugate $\gamma$ by that element, the result is an element $\gamma_1 = \delta\gamma\delta^{-1}$ of the form $\gamma_1(z) = e^{2 \pi i r} z$ or $e^{-2 \pi i r} z$.

What else is there to say? ... The map $\gamma'$ preserves the family of  circles centered on the origin; those circles limit down to $0$ in the inward direction and $\infty$ in the outward direction, acting as an irrational rotation on each such circle. It follows that $\gamma$ preserves a family of circles limiting down to $P$ on one direction and $Q$ in the other direction, acting by a map which is conjugate to the irrational rotation.